# Store custom text in windows registry is a good idea?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I made a Windows image (with sysprep), and probably I will do changes on it and rebuild it, so I will have some computers with and old version of my image and other with a newer version.

I may need some way to know what image version it's installed on a computer and I'm thinking about create a custom key entry in Windows Registry (regedit) to store this information, for example:

```
KEY HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyImage 
Value Version
Data 1.0
```

Anyone can see some kind of problem doing that?

Thanks for share your opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't be a problem, as long as you're making a key unique to your usage and it doesn't clash with any other keys on the system.